# How can I get code analysis to recognize mixed case custom words as a valid identifier?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I'm using code analysis in my project, and have several mixed case words which I want to be considered valid words (e.g. ReSharper.)

I have added a [`CustomDictionary.xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx#bkmk_dictionarywordsrecognizedword) file, but I can't figure out how to configure it to recognize just my word as valid **without also recognizing just its prefix**.

This doesn't suppress all of the errors, I still get "Correct the casing of 'Re' in type name 'ReSharper' by changing it to 'RE'." and "The compound word 'ReSharper' in type name 'ReSharper' exists as a discrete term. If your usage is intended to be single word, case it as 'Resharper'."

```
<Dictionary>
    <Words>
        <Recognized>
            <Word>ReSharper</Word>
            <Word>resharper</Word>
        </Recognized>
    </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

The following solution suppresses the warnings I'm getting, but is too broad:

```
<Dictionary>
    <Words>
        <Recognized>
            <Word>Re</Word>
        </Recognized>
    </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

How can I get code analysis to not give me spelling or casing suggestions for "ReSharper", but to correctly identify other incorrect words like "RePair"?

Comment: Just add ReSharper as a recognised word, after all it's an ExCeption...

Comment: I still get "Correct the casing of 'Re' in type name 'ReSharper' by changing it to 'RE'." and "The compound word 'ReSharper' in type name 'ReSharper' exists as a discrete term. If your usage is intended to be single word, case it as 'Resharper'."

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx):

> To include a term in the list of terms that code analysis identifies as a compound word and to specify the correct casing of the term, add the term as the inner text of a Dictionary/Words/Compound/Term element. In the CompoundAlternate attribute of the Term element, specify the individual words that make up the compound term by capitalizing the first letter of the individual words (Pascal case).

In your case, this would look like:

```
<Dictionary>
      <Words>
         <Compound>
            <Term CompoundAlternate="ReSharper">resharper</Term>
            ...
         </Compound>
         ...
      </Words>
      ...
</Dictionary>
```